# How to count the siblings

Tags: java, xml, xpath, stax

i have xml files structured as follows:

**xml example**:

```
<node id="613220929" lat="49.21352" lon="8.60406"/>
<node id="613220996" lat="49.23941" lon="8.60184"/>
<node id="613220997" lat="49.24894" lon="8.60214"/>
<node id="613221003" lat="49.234" lon="8.6032152"/>
<node id="613221004" lat="49.25639" lon="8.60311"/>
<node id="613221005" lat="49.25942" lon="8.60763"/>
<node id="613221006" lat="49.20332" lon="8.60349"/>
<node id="613221055" lat="49.21245" lon="8.60363"/>
<node id="613221056" lat="49.29341" lon="8.6036"/>
<node id="613221061" lat="49.29257" lon="8.60353"/>
<node id="613343245" lat="49.2582" lon="8.42486"/>
<node id="613343379" lat="49.27044" lon="8.45762"/>
<tag k="waterway:maxspeed" v="12"/>
</osm>
```

and i wrote the below code to display info about the first sibling, but the problem is, some of the xml files has more than Tag elemen, and i do not know how can i know inadvance the number of siblings "the Tag elements"?

**code**:

```
String expr0 = "//node[@lat='11122'][@lon='111222']/following-sibling::tag[1]/@v";
    xPath.compile(expr0);
    String s = (String) xPath.evaluate(expr0, document, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: @raghavendra as some of the xml files has more than one Tag element, i want to count the number of tag elements available in the xml file

Comment: then you can just use count(//tag)